# Batch for loop w/ multiple commands

Tags: string, batch-file, for-loop

Any idea why this wouldn't work? I'm trying to create a file scanning all batch files in it's current directory for a specific string (123456) and if found proceed to :end. If not found, the file should copy itself into the scanned file and proceed scanning the next file. Any ideas and tips are appreciated! Cheers!

```
    for %%f in (*.bat) do (
        set A=%%f
        set file=%A%
        findstr "123456" %file%
        if %errorlevel%==0 goto end
        copy %0 %A%
        )
    :end
```

I tested the following code:

```
    SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
    for %%f in (*.bat) do (
         set A=%%~f
         set file=%A%
        findstr "123456" %file%
        if %errorlevel%==0 goto end
        copy %0 %A%
        )
    :end
```

and the code didnt execute the goto end command. The output looks like this:

```
    C:\Users\Epidex98\Desktop\routine>(
    set A=ir.bat
     set file=
      findstr "123456"
     if 0 == 0 goto end
     copy "C:\Users\Epidex98\Desktop\routine\ir.bat"
    )
```

Comment: Remember to test this in a folder that holds the only copies of the other scripts you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%f in (*.bat) do (
    set A=%%~f
    set file=!A!
    findstr "123456" !file!
    if !errorlevel!==0 goto :end
    copy %0 !A!
    )
:end
```

or simpler

```
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%f in (*.bat) do (
    findstr "123456" "%%~f"
    if !errorlevel!==0 goto :end
    copy %0 "%%~f"
    )
:end
```

However, if you can't apply delayed expansion for some reason:

```
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for %%f in (*.bat) do (
    set A=%%f
    call :proc
    if errorlevel 0 goto :end
    copy %0 %%f
    )
rem next command skips :proc subroutine 
goto :end

:proc
  set file=%A%
  findstr "123456" %file%
  set /A myerror=%errorlevel%-1
exit /B %myerror%

:end
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (helpful particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~f` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (special page) [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)